# class weblogic.security.spi.WLSUser in WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

Tags: weblogic12c

I need to use class `weblogic.security.spi.WLSUser` that in previous versions os WL was located in the library **wls-api-10.3.jar**.

But I don't find this library in WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the same version 12.1.2.0.0, maybe you've found the solution already by this time, but I'm posting here anyway for somebody who is searching for this library that is located in:
 **Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar**
[image]

Hope it helps people who is having problems finding this library.

Regards.